# What are the difference between Cherry-pick and patch apply?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I am aware about git cherry-pick and git apply terminalogies. But today i came across with some issue. I was applying one patch by using the diff of two revisions. I used the below command:

> git diff HEAD  > diff.patch
>
> git apply diff.patch

I got patch apply failed for one file.

Then i simply tried to **cherry-pick** the commit-id2. It is cherry-picked successfully.

What may be the reason? Anyone wants to throw some light on the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- The changes in `diff.patch` are probably different from the changes in `commit-id2`, which is why the two behaved differently.

  `git diff HEAD` shows the diff between `HEAD` and the current working directory.  `git cherry-pick commit-id2` applies the diff between `commit-id2` and its parent (and commits the result using the metadata from `commit-id2`).  The diff between `commit-id2` and its parent is not (usually) the same as the diff between `HEAD` and the current working directory.
- You did not tell `git apply` to fall back to a 3-way merge like `cherry-pick` does.  Try adding the `--3way` (or `-3`) option to `git apply`.

Try the following:

```
git diff commit-id2^! >diff.patch
git apply -3 diff.patch
```

The above should behave like `git cherry-pick -n commit-id2`.  (See [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/gitrevisions) for an explanation of the `^!` syntax.)