# How to raise a conflict for this git cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Two branches `master` and `foo` point to the same root commit A. The work tree has only one file `bar.txt`.

```
$cat bar.txt
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

Make Commit B to `master`, adding a line in `bar.txt`.

```
$cat bar.txt
11111
22222
33333
aaaaa
44444
55555
```

Then make Commit C to `master`, deleting `aaaaa` and adding `bbbbb` elsewhere in `bar.txt`.

```
$cat bar.txt
11111
bbbbb
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

Run `git format-patch -1 C` to generate the patch for Commit C, assuming its name to be `0001-bbbbb.patch`.

Now checkout `foo`. `git am 00001-bbbbb.patch` or `git apply 00001-bbbbb.patch` will fail due to conflicts, as expected. However `git cherry-pick C` will succeed without any problem.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198013) I learn that `git am` or `git apply` will succeed too with the argument `-3` or `--3way` in this case. However I cannot find any config or argument about three way merge for `git cherry-pick`.

Question:

How to disable the three-way-merge thing for `git cherry-pick` in this case, so that the cherry-pick will fail?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the patch, you could try adjusting the number of context lines. The deafult is 3, so you would get overlap of the changes across the context lines. Dropping to 2 context lines would allow the 22222\n33333 pair to provide a clear context. Meanwhile the Cherry-pick already knows alot more about your repo so can make sensible decisions about the merge base and context lines (the different parts of the merge tactics can be quite detailed to ensure success when possible, and reporting of conflicts when not)

Comment: Supplementary: Why would you want the cherry-pick to fail?? (rather than having a patch that properly succeeds?)

Comment: @PhilipOakley after reading your comments I feel my expectation is somehow unreasonable. Is it true that a patch cannot be applied with no 3way merge, if the current context is different from the one the patch is related to? I guess without 3way merge most of the cherry-pick won't succeed at all.

Comment: The 'context' is the few lines either side of the change that the diff uses to ensure that the change is being applied in the right place. You can increase the number of context lines if you want to be realy pedantic about where the change applies in the file (think of all those close bracket lines that could be confused..), or you can shrink the context so that a known overlap doesn't get in the way. When doing a cherry-pick, a 3-way is (almost) always possible, but not for a basic (emailed) patch, so different considerations apply.

Comment: If you create a separate repo, and prefix all the example with an extra initial line, and then generate the format-patch from that. Now see if you can apply that patch change sucessfully. I suspect that because the starting file was different, though the change identical, the --3way fall back won't work because the fall back can't find that alternate start point (as listed in the git diff index line) in the other repo, so can't fall back to it (in your example case it does have it). In that alternate case the patch would require manual resolution because of the lack of a common context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the merge strategy when using `git cherry-pick`.  The strategies available are listed here: https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies.

EDIT: `octopus` is not actually the correct merge strategy in this case since it also fails with a valid cherry-pick (as @Elpiekay pointed out)

I'm not sure any of the other valid cherry-pick merge strategies (and options) will result in the same behavior as the `git apply` above.  I'd be happy to be proven wrong though!

> I think you probably want `octopus`, so your command would be:
>
> git cherry-pick --strategy=octopus C
>
> When I tested it, it gave me this error:
>
> error: could not apply 62f20c5... C

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. But `octopus` seems not suitable in this case. It deals with more than two heads. `git cherry-pick --strategy=octopus B` fails too. So this could not be a generic solution.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate!  I'm not sure there's a way to cherry pick the way you want without exporting it with either `git diff` or `git format-patch` and `git apply`ing the result.